# Automatically apply different fonts based on text/symbol

Tags: fonts, adobe-indesign, automation, symbols

I'm working on layout for a 300-page trilingual “coffee table” style textbook, and [one of the languages](http://guampedia.com/chamorro-orthography-rules/) uses a glottal stop symbol which the chosen body text font can't handle. This means that for every instance of this symbol, the font must change to TNR and then back to the font of the main body text.

I sincerely hope there a way I can automate this, perhaps with styles. At the moment I'm using a find-replace to change the fonts individually and semi-manually, which is tedious and accident-prone.

**Is there a tool or method in InDesign which will automatically recognize a particular symbol and change its font whenever that symbol appears?**

Answer (score 7):

Yes! It's  called **GREP  styles**,  and you'll  find it  under  **paragraph styles**.

It  allows you to enter a "regular  expression" (AKA "regex", a code-based  super powerful advanced search),  then,  it applies a  character  style of your choice to anything   that  matches  those  criteria,  instantly  and  automatically.  If you  edit  text  so  a  snippet  no  longer  matches  the  criteria,  the  character style falls  off.

For something  simple  like  matching  one character, just  copying and   pasting  that one  character  in  should  do  the  job (or  it  might  be  listed  as a  special  character).

For  more sophisticated   things,  it  gives  you a  menu  of  options  to  choose  from -  the  trick is  patience, and lots of trial and error.

Comment: So any time I add text containing the symbol, it'll automatically get re-styled? *Sweet*.

Comment: Yes -  it  applies  it to any  text with that  style  matching  those  criteria  any time instantly.  If  you want the rule to apply to all text everywhere,  apply the  rule  to  the  default  basic  paragraph  style.  It's a  good idea  to  use a really clear  obvious  character style when testing a grep  rule -  with  preview  ticked,  it's  easy  to  tweak  until  it's right

Comment: @user568458 Does GREP work with character blocks? For example, if I want to use one font for the hiragana and katakana blocks and another for all the CJK character blocks.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw In theory it should work, using a pattern like `[a-z]` (square brackets = any of these; hyphen inside square brackets = include everything within this range). Do some searches for things  like 'regex katakana', 'regex hiragana', 'regex japanese', finds some examples like [this sample](https://gist.github.com/terrancesnyder/1345094) which suggests blocks like `[ぁ-ん]` or `[ぁ-ゔゞ゛゜ー]`. I don't know if they work in InDesign however (they should do, unless Adobe messed up their version of regex, which is entirely possible).